# EF Stored proc with encryption based column is throwing operand clash exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I am trying to call the stored proc from the EF 6. SearchField2Param is the nvarchar based column with the size 20. And this parameter is going into the SP under the table column which is encrypted with the "always encrypt" feature.

**Exception :- Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(20)** encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC')

Somehow i have this feeling that the sqlparameter is unable to make column with nvarchar(20) size to match the target db column.

```
SeachField1Param = new SqlParameter("SearchField1", SearchField1);
    SearchField2Param = new SqlParameter("SearchField2",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)
                    {
                        Value = SearchField2
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        return this.ExecuteProcedure("dbo.InsertSearch", SeachField1Param, SearchField2Param);
                    }



public static int ExecuteProcedure(this DbContext context, string procedureName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            string sql = SqlCommandHelper.GetSqlCommandString(procedureName, parameters);
            return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
        }
```

Comment: You didn't specified the size for `SeachField1Param`. Construct it the same way as you do with `SearchField2Param` and try again.

Comment: But SearchField1Param is a simple nvarchar(20) based column.

Comment: Not specifying the size of parameters can lead to awful results in general. Don't do this! And in this particular case, it is a stored procedure parameter, as the second one. How you use them inside the stored procedure isn't important. This most likely is the reason for client parametrization for Always Encrypted to not work properly.